# Is there a better way to enumerate text elements from an IEnumerable<char>?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I want to enumerate text elements (groups of Unicode code points that are displayed as single character, like `e`+`´`=`é`) from an `IEnumerable<char>`. Right now I have the following:

```
// This code is untested! I assume it works because it's fairly simple and I checked the specification though.
public static IEnumerable<string> AsTextElements(this IEnumerable<char> input)
{
    StringBuilder currentElement = new StringBuilder();
    char highSurrogate = (char)0;
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        // Assuming input contains valid UTF-16:
        if (char.IsHighSurrogate(c))
        {
            highSurrogate = c;
            continue;
        }

        int codepoint;
        if (char.IsLowSurrogate(c))
        { codepoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(highSurrogate, c); }
        else
        { codepoint = c; }

        var codepointString = char.ConvertFromUtf32(codepoint);
        var category = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(codepointString, 0);

        switch (category)
        {
            // Do these catch all combining characters?
            case UnicodeCategory.EnclosingMark:
            case UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark:
            case UnicodeCategory.SpacingCombiningMark:
                if (currentElement == null)
                { currentElement = new StringBuilder(codepointString); }
                else
                { currentElement.Append(codepointString); }
                break;
            default:
                if (currentElement.Length != 0)
                {
                    yield return currentElement.ToString();
                    currentElement.Clear();
                }
                currentElement.Append(codepointString);
                break;
        }
    }
    yield return currentElement.ToString();
}
```

What irks me about this are all the `codepointString` `string`s being created here, even though I need at most 32 bits for each code point. **I couldn't find a method that gets the Unicode category directly from an `int` or two `char`s.**
Adding the `char`(s) to the `currentElement` `StringBuilder` is easily possible though.

I'm aware of the "measure before optimizing" advice, this question is mainly because it would seem strange to me if if wasn't possible without heap allocations.
I didn't have to iterate text elements without having them available in the same `string` so far, but I may in the future.

Comment: Note that your code incorrectly calculates supplementary code points: it's not as simple as shifting the high surrogate by 16 and adding the low surrogates.  I'm aware that it says it's untested, but that's one big thing I notice.

Comment: @PeterO. This should fix it.

Comment: Isn't this kind of like [StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f3k4f6(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Are you re-implementing String.Normalize()???

Comment: Neither. `StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator` requires the full input to be already available and `String.Normalize(...)` does something _entirely_ different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by text elements you mean "user-perceived characters", then [Unicode Standard Annex 29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/) contains an algorithm for finding the boundaries between "extended grapheme clusters", which may better correspond to "user-perceived characters" than the code points resulting from normalization.

(My previous answer was incorrect, so I deleted it; it suggested using normalization form C, but it's inadequate for finding text elements in many cases.)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need - and also likely more correct than what I have now. I'll see if I can implement this and then update the question with the solution.